# Unable to Read large CSV File with Apache Commons CSV - IllegalArgumentException. Small file working

Tags: java

I am parsing a CSV file using Apache CSV Commons. When I used a small file with few rows, it works fine. When I used a file of 2MB, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Mapping for Employee not found, expected one of [Employee, Full name, Date, Type, Registration, Amount]
    at org.apache.commons.csv.CSVRecord.get(CSVRecord.java:121) ~[commons-csv-1.9.0.jar:1.9.0]
```

---

```java
for(CSVRecord record: csvParser){
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for(String column : userColumns){
        System.out.println(column);
        System.out.println(column.length());
        System.out.println(record);
        System.out.println(record.get("Employee"));

        //the line with the error
        stringBuilder.append(record.get(column)).append("\t");
    }
}
```

I don't get the error when I use a CSV file of 300 rows, only with large CSV files.

> Failed to complete request: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Mapping for Employee not found, expected one of [Employee, Full name, Donation Date, Donation Type, Charity Registration, Charity Name, Donation Amount, Matching Gift]

Comment: Probably an error in the input file.

Comment: Catch the exception and print out the data at that time.  I think you will find it is a data problem.

Comment: It may be EOF , or a blank line at end of file fouling the for().   ctoy ilee boodoo stReelyet